# '~ and many more.' vs. '~and much more.'

Tags: countability

We have a grammar rule here. 'many more + a countable noun' and 'much more + an uncountable noun,' Right?

But how about '~ and much more.' in the following sentence? Is it grammatically correct to use it at the end of a sentence?

How about using '~ and many more.'? I think '~ and many more (ethnic goods)' is better.

> The Little Penang Street Market is known as the best place to see local crafts, and it really was full of beautiful ethnic goods, including clothes, shoes, wood carvings, woven baskets, and **much more**.

Comment: "much more" works the best here, but I can't figure out how to explain why

Comment: And much more [than all that] or many more _goods_.

Answer (score 1):

When the sentence ends with "much more" or "many more" it is equivalent "much/many more **than that**", with "that" referring to the objects that appear earlier in the sentence. "Many more" can be used of all the objects are of the same type, forming a list, such as in

> If you go on a safari tour you will see see wild animals: zebras, giraffes, elephants, and many more.

But if the intent is to intensify the word "more",  then you should use "much":

> This hotel is in an excellent location. Within walking distance you have shops, parks, theaters, restaurants, and much more.

As for your question, of the intent is to continue the list of *ethnic goods*, then you should use "many more". But if you use the word "more" to refer to things beyond ethnic goods, then "much more" can be used to emphasize it.

See also [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers#much-with-comparative-adjectives-and-adverbs-much-older-much-faster) and another discussion at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/47918/164776).

Answer (score 0):

It can help if you imagine what could come after "more."

> The Little Penang Street Market is known as the best place to see
>   local crafts, and it really was full of beautiful ethnic goods,
>   including clothes, shoes, wood carvings, woven baskets, and **much
>   more *stuff.***

or

> The Little Penang Street Market is known as the best place to see
>   local crafts, and it really was full of beautiful ethnic goods,
>   including clothes, shoes, wood carvings, woven baskets, and **many more *goods.***